# How to get the property that has a DataMemberAttribute with a specified name?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, properties, propertyinfo

How can I reflectively get the property that has the DataMember with a given name (let's assume every DataMember has a unique name)? For example, in the following code the property with the DataMember that has name "p1" is `PropertyOne`:

```
[DataContract(Name = "MyContract")]
public class MyContract
{
    [DataMember(Name = "p1")]
    public string PropertyOne { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "p2")]
    public string PropertyTwo { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "p3")]
    public string PropertyThree { get; set; }
}
```

Currently, I have:

```
string dataMemberName = ...;

var dataMemberProperties = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DataMemberAttribute), false).Any());

var propInfo = dataMemberProperties.Where(p => ((DataMemberAttribute)p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DataMemberAttribute), false).First()).Name == dataMemberName).FirstOrDefault();
```

This works, but it feels like it could be improved. I particularly don't like that `GetCustomAttributes()` is called twice.

How can it be re-written better? Ideally, it would be great if I could make it a simple one-liner.

Comment: It would be more efficient to first filter out members that do not have a `DataMemberAttribute` at all, and only load the attribute data for those that have it. Use the [`Attribute.IsDefined` static method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fdf7hf1.aspx "MSDN reference page") for this purpose... It's more efficient than `GetCustomAttribute`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
// using System.Linq;
// using System.Reflection;
// using System.Runtime.Serialization;
obj.GetType()
   .GetProperties(…)
   .Where(p => Attribute.IsDefined(p, typeof(DataMemberAttribute)))
   .Single(p => ((DataMemberAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(
                    p, typeof(DataMemberAttribute))).Name == "Foo");
```

**Notes:**

- [`Attribute.IsDefined`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fdf7hf1.aspx) is used to check for the presence of a custom attribute without retrieving its data. Thus it is more efficient than `Attribute.GetCustomAttribute` and used to skip properties in a first step.
- After the `Where` operator, we are left with properties that have *exactly one* `DataMemberAttribute`: Properties without this attribute have been filtered out, and it cannot be applied more than once. Therefore we can use `Attribute.GetCustomAttribute` instead of `Attribute.GetCustomAttributes`.

Answer (score 3):

You could use LINQ:

```
string dataMemberName = ...;
var propInfo =
    (from property in typeof(T).GetProperties()
    let attributes = property
        .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DataMemberAttribute), false)
        .OfType<DataMemberAttribute>()
    where attributes.Any(a => a.Name == dataMemberName)
    select property).FirstOrDefault();
```

or if you prefer:

```
string dataMemberName = ...;
var propInfo = typeof(T)
    .GetProperties()
    .Where(p => p
        .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DataMemberAttribute), false)
        .OfType<DataMemberAttribute>()
        .Any(x => x.Name == dataMemberName)
    )
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Fasterflect](http://fasterflect.codeplex.com) to make your reflection code simpler and easier on the eyes:

```
var property = typeof(T).MembersAndAttributes( MemberTypes.Property, typeof(DataMemberAttribute) )
    .Where( ma => ma.Attributes.First().Name == dataMemberName )
    .Select( ma => ma.Member as PropertyInfo )
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

If you only need to check for the presence of the attribute, something like this could be used instead:

```
var property = typeof(T).PropertiesWith<DataMemberAttribute>( Flags.InstancePublic )
    .Where( p => p.Name == dataMemberName ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Fasterflect comes with a nice set of extension methods and includes some neat performance optimizations using IL generation if you also need speed.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to get the value of the property and not the property itself so used [Darin Dimitrov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14671540/971299) but added `.GetValue(this)` to the end to return the value instead.

Here is what my class ended up looking like:

```
[DataContract]
public class Item
{
    [DataMember(Name = "kpiId")]
    public string KPIId { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "unit")]
    public string Unit{ get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "category")]
    public string Category { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "source")]
    public string Source { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "messages")]
    public SysMessage[] Messages { get; set; }

    public object getDataMemberByName(string name)
    {
         return (typeof(Item).GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DataMemberAttribute), false)
                              .OfType<DataMemberAttribute>()
                              .Any(x => x.Name == name))).GetValue(this);
    }
}
```