# Getting the name of [DataMember] in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

I have the model class like the following,

```
public class Station
{
    [DataMember (Name="stationName")]
    public string StationName;
    [DataMember (Name="stationId")]
    public string StationId;
}
```

I would like to get the Name of `DataMember` with Property Name, i.e If I have the property name "StationName", How can I get the `stationName`?

Comment: Please Refer( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14671507/how-to-get-the-property-that-has-a-datamemberattribute-with-a-specified-name)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the property that has a DataMemberAttribute with a specified name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14671507/how-to-get-the-property-that-has-a-datamemberattribute-with-a-specified-name)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A slight modification to your class

```
[DataContract]
public class Station
{
    [DataMember(Name = "stationName")]
    public string StationName { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "stationId")]
    public string StationId { get; set; }
}
```

and then this is how you can get it

```
 var properties = typeof(Station).GetProperties();
 foreach (var property in properties)
 {
    var attributes = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DataMemberAttribute), true);
     foreach (DataMemberAttribute dma in attributes)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(dma.Name);
      }                
  }
```

Comment: Ok, GetProperties is for WP7, you're right. Without modification of the class you can use this to get all members, being a property or a field: For WP7, `var members = typeof(Station).GetMembers;`. For WP8, `var members = typeof(Station).GetTypeInfo().DeclaredMembers;`

Answer (score 3):

I created an extension method:

```
        public static string GetDataMemberName(this MyClass theClass, string thePropertyName)
    {
        var pi = typeof(MyClass).GetProperty(thePropertyName);
        if (pi == null) throw new ApplicationException($"{nameof(MyClass)}.{thePropertyName} does not exist");
        var ca = pi.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DataMemberAttribute), true) as DataMemberAttribute;
        if (ca == null) throw new ApplicationException($"{nameof(MyClass)}.{thePropertyName} does not have DataMember Attribute"); // or return thePropertyName?
        return ca.Name;
    }
```

with usage

```
myInstance.GetDataMemberName(nameof(MyClass.MyPropertyName)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it simply by using the [`Reflection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx), `cast` that return attribute to [`DataMemberAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class and read the Name `property value`.

[Here](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/30250) is a complete 3rd party example.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class TypeExtensions
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the nameofMember's DataMemberAttribute.Name
    /// Example usage:
    /// var aPropertyDataMemberName = typeof(MyType).GetDataMemberName(nameof(MyType.AProperty));
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="type">The type. Example: typeof(MyType)</param>
    /// <param name="nameofMember">The member of the type. Example: nameof(MyType.AProperty)</param>
    /// <param name="throwIfMemberDoesntExist">Optionally throw if the member does not exist</param>
    /// <returns>nameofMember's DataMemberAttribute.Name
    /// </returns>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException">Thrown if the member does not exist</exception>
    public static string? GetDataMemberName(this Type type, string nameofMember, bool throwIfMemberDoesNotExist = true)
    {
        MemberInfo? memberInfo = type?.GetProperty(nameofMember) ?? type?.GetField(nameofMember) ?? type?.GetMember(nameofMember)?.FirstOrDefault();
        string? ret = (memberInfo?.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DataMemberAttribute), true) as DataMemberAttribute)?.Name ?? string.Empty;
        if (memberInfo == null && throwIfMemberDoesNotExist) { throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(nameofMember), "Member does not exist."); }
        return ret;
    }
}
```